# Torque in torsional pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Just having a small doubt in torsional pendulum. Everywhere I have read that in torsional pendulum $\tau = -c\theta$ . However I am not able to understand about which point, this torque has been written. Can any one please provide an insight into this. Also, please tell me in which direction the force has been applied. A diagram would be much help. I tried searching the web but only thing that I found was $\tau = -c\theta$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's a lot of information about a torsion pendulum system been abstracted away given the basic $\tau = -c\theta$ equation. Essentially, the string in a torsion pendulum has a non-zero thickness, and is typically fixed at one end. This means that as you wind up a torsion pendulum, you're creating a twist in the string relative to the anchor point. That twist will generate a shear force throughout the non-zero thickness of any slice of the string, which will act to untwist the string. That shear force will act perpendicular to the central axis of the string, and create the torque that's represented in the equation for a torsional pendulum.

The specific form of that equation can be understood as follows. Assume that the restoring shear force is some function of the displacement angle. $F_{shear}=-f(\theta)$. Then the torque created on the string is found $\tau=r\times F$, for simplicity we can assume that the force acts perpendicularly to the central string axis and assume that the thickness of the string is small, so that $\tau\approx rF_{shear}=-rf(\theta)$. Any function $f(\theta)$ can be expanded into a Taylor series, which allows us to drop higher order terms so that $\tau=-rf'(0)\theta=-c\theta$ since $r$ would be constant of the string.